# Rendering CMS Paragraph component content and script in Spartacus

Tags: angular, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I have Created Spartacus Angular project with version 6.3.0 and I have added html content and inline scripts inside  paragraph component in SmartEdit. While loading the page in browser I am seeing this error in console like below and inline script is not able to load and execute.

**`WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content, see https://g.co/ng/security#xss`**

If anyone knows please let me know how to load and execute inline script in Spartacus application. whether I need to add any configuration .

Comment: This is not a Spartacus problem, it's a general use of limited trust to execute code from the server. In Angular, you need to use DomSanitizer. Please see related questions, there are examples with component methods or pipe or just check the OOTB paragraph component implementation. Commit changes show how it was done before (pipe) and currently (method). https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/commit/e0e51a20608954d66108bd0c974e08abd1225342

Answer (score 0):

we are using JavaScript and Jquery libraries Like Slick.JS etc. in HTML using paragraph component.
CSS is working fine but JavaScript is not working.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```